# How to build a Horizontal list images container using Ant design and Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, components, antd

I am using Ant Design UI in my application. I've searched for results but Google doesn't show me the clearly way for my case.

According the design, I have to build the layout for each of tabs (image).
Could you give me some advises for building this layout? Thank you for your helps!

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to provide any coding assistance if you don't have your attempts posted. That being said, the only AntDesign component I see being utilized is [`Grid`](https://ant.design/components/grid/). You'd then have to build 2 custom `divs` along your grid row. First `div` spans 18 columns with `overflow-x` set to auto, second `div` spans the remaining 6 columns. First `div` encompasses the scrolling list. Second `div` encompasses the image previewer.